# Open source concept mining tools?

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, concept

Are there to day any [concept mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_mining) open source tools available? I have only be coming across like [Leximancer](https://www.leximancer.com/), which although seem to fit the role is not open source and quite expensive for a undergraduate student. I have been unsuccessful so far since the word 'concept' on both google and google scholar seems to be un-matching what I want.

Comment: I do not have much idea about concept mining, but as a data miner, I usually use WEKA. Is it not appropriate for your work?

Comment: Unfortunately no. For starts the purpose of the concept mining to my needs is to apply on text mining to extract concepts, I don't think weka is targeted to that but to data mining, that is, more into the structured part I believe.

Comment: I think you need to explain, clearly, what a 'concept mining tool' *is*, and perhaps (if possible) what sort of input you expect and what sort of output you'd expect.

Comment: I linked the words concept mining on my original question to the wiki definition and provided an example tool..

Comment: This sounds to me like topic modelling + graphing.  Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) is a common method.  I've used gensim in python but there are other implementations (scikit-learn in python, Mallet, Apache Mahout).  For graphing,  gephi is a justifiably popular standalone open source tool.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you need a text mining tool for clustering. [RapidMiner](http://rapid-i.com/) has an open-source, Java based Community Edition which has several extensions (Text Mining, R, etc.). In addition you can develop and integrate your own algorithms too.

Moreover [Rexer Analytics](http://www.rexeranalytics.com/) offers a comprehensive data mining survey annually, you can call for reports for free.